# Drop group of stored procedures by name

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have group of stored procedures with names like 'somename_%'. Are there any way to delete that SP with one query, forexample

> DROP PROCEDURE where name like
>   'somename_%'

.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works for MSSQL 2005 +

```
DECLARE @DropScript varchar(max)
set @DropScript = ''

SELECT @DropScript = @DropScript + 'DROP PROCEDURE [' + schema_name(schema_id)+ '].' + '[' + name + ']
' FROM sys.procedures
where name like 'somename_%'


exec (@DropScript)
```

Comment: It worked great for me, too. Erased about 200 sp from a lame instalation of a program! Thnx!

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the DDL by querying the data dictionary. For example, in Oracle:

```
SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE "'||owner||'"."'||object_name||'";'
FROM all_procedures
WHERE procedure_name IS NULL
AND lower(object_name) LIKE 'somename_%';
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I always tend to do these kind of things is just extract the list procedures from the system tables using my critierion and then create the command list - either direct in sql e.g. `SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE ' + procName FROM system_procedures_table WHERE procName like...` or in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

In MS_Sql-Server you cn create a Statement with all the relevant Procedures to drop through (ab)using the "FOR XML PATH ('')" clause...

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
GO
CREATE PROC Test_1  AS
BEGIN;
  PRINT '1'
END;
GO
CREATE PROC Test_2  AS
BEGIN;
  PRINT '2'
END;
GO
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name LIKE 'Test%'  AND   TYPE = 'P';
DECLARE @Stmt NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Stmt = ( SELECT 'DROP PROC ' + STUFF (x.Stmt, 1, 2, SPACE(0))
              FROM  (SELECT ', ' + SCHEMA_NAME(Obj.Schema_ID) + CHAR(46) + Obj.Name
                     FROM   sys.objects AS Obj
                     WHERE  Obj.name LIKE 'Test%' 
                      AND   obj.TYPE = 'P'
                     FOR XML PATH ('')
                    ) AS X (Stmt)
            );
SELECT @Stmt;
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @Stmt;
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name LIKE 'Test%'  AND   TYPE = 'P';
ROLLBACK;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check this TSQL script that automatically drops a list of stored procedures](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/tsql/drop-list-of-stored-procedures).

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.