# Drop several stored procs in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have about 100 temporary stored procs in my database. How can I quickly drop all stored procs that have 'tempZZZ' in their names?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drop group of stored procedures by name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446003/drop-group-of-stored-procedures-by-name)

Comment: If they are truly temporary procedures you can just close the connection. If they are not temporary procedure but persistent procedures that you only needed for a short time this won't work.

Comment: Sorry @LittleBobbyTables. Am I supposed to delete this question then?

Comment: @WebDevGuy - you can't, since there are multiple upvoted answers.  Until it's closed and eventually deleted, it'll just remain around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

    SELECT @sql += N'DROP PROCEDURE dbo.'
      + QUOTENAME(name) + ';
    ' FROM sys.procedures
    WHERE name LIKE N'tempZZZ%'
AND
     SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = N'dbo';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to get SQL Server to generate your SQL using the system tables:

```
SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE ['+name+']'
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE name LIKE '%tempZZZ%'
```

Then paste the output of that into your SSMS window and run it. You may need to modify it if you have procedures in different schemas.

**Warning**: Make sure you check the output before you run it!